# Added route drops inadvertently in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, routing

On my Ubuntu 16.04 I'm using local net and mobile internet via Android phone. I'm completely novice at routing but this is what I have. Just after connecting phone I have routes table:

```
default via 10.205.103.1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100
default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s29f7u5  proto static  metric 101 
10.205.32.136 via 10.205.103.1 dev enp2s0  proto dhcp  metric 100 
10.205.103.0/24 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.205.103.53  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s29f7u5  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.42.72  metric 100
```

To have local net (gate 10.205.103.1) and internet both I used

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.42.129 metric 2
sudo route add -net 10.205.0.0/16 gw 10.205.103.1 metric 1
```

So I have

```
default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s29f7u5  metric 2 
default via 10.205.103.1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100 
default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s29f7u5  proto static  metric 101 
10.205.0.0/16 via 10.205.103.1 dev enp2s0  scope link  metric 1
etc.
```

All work good, these 2 routes have been added to the table but I have a problem because of some mysterious for me reason - my first route drops every some minutes (~10-15, don't know what it depends on) and I got another table:

```
default via 10.205.103.1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100 
default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s29f7u5  proto static  metric 101
10.205.0.0/16 via 10.205.103.1 dev enp2s0  scope link  metric 1
etc.
```

So I have to re-run  command `sudo route add default gw 192.168.42.129 metric 2`. Why does it happen and how to avoid it? Removing default route via 192.168.42.129 (that one with metric 101) before adding mine has no effect - when my created route drops this route returns into table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do this with network-manager (in GUI/desktop network settings so) not on bash directly.

For 10.205.103.1 in IPv4 settings / Routes... / uncheck:

> use this connection only for resources on its network

Your route table should be clean this way and it resists unplugs and reboots.